# How to install grub2 on second disk and using EFI on first disk

Tags: grub2, grub-efi

I want to try to install Ubuntu 16.04 on a new laptop. This laptop has 64 GB eMMC storage which has pre-installed Windows 10. I don't want to change anything or break Windows installation. Because I don't own this laptop, I only borrow it for several days. I want to return it to the owner as original as I took it from him. But I want to install and test if this laptop compatible with linux or not.

So I put a 16 GB micro sd card to card slot of laptop, plug Ubuntu 16.04 installation USB pen-drive to USB slot and installed it. I followed these steps:

64 GB eMMC storage seen as emmcblk0 and it has 4 GPT partitions One of them is EFI partition.

16 GB sd card seen as emmcblk1 and I formatted it as one ext4 partition and emmcblk1p1 used for root partition during installation steps. I did not create any other EFI or swap partitions.

I choose to install bootloader to emmcblk1 (I tried with another installation to emmcblk1p1 and I get same result). I did not choose to install to emmcblk0 because I don't want to change anything 64 GB eMMC Windows disk.

When I try to boot system, I get 2 EFI entries called "ubuntu", and If I try to boot from one of them system drops to GRUB2 shell prompt. When I run ls command, I can only see (hd0,gpt1) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt4) entries. These are 64 GB eMMC drive's GPT partitions and I don't see emmcblk1 from GRUB2 shell.

What should I do from this point? What's wrong with this installation steps?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You poosibly made changes to your friends system already.
Please create a bootinfo-summary following the steps in this link:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info
If you use boot-repair don't click the "recommended repair"-button, this would possibly make more changes to the system.
Post the given URL so we can see what happend to your friends system and are able to give advice.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Here is the link for report:
http://paste2.org/3PPbx30w

On the other hand, I didn't mentioned, I already tried to fix with boot repair 2 times and these are their reports:
http://paste2.org/CDDFX95g
http://paste2.org/I9UJn57n

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Your action added a few file to the ESP (EFI System Partition).The ESP is mmcblk0p1. The files are in a single folder with the name "/ubuntu".

Comment: Ok. If I delete ubuntu folder under mmcblk0p1/EFI/ubuntu my friend's computer will be as original. But how can I install and boot ubuntu to mmcblk1? grub2 can't see mmcblk1.

Comment: Shutdown, remove your micro sd card and pendrive, boot directly to mmcblk0 and see what happens. If the machine boots directly to Windows you shouldn't delete this files.

Comment: Windows boots normally. There is no problem with Windows. But I still can't boot ubuntu.

Comment: Read this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromSD). It is not as easy to make bootable installtion and needs changes to your friends system. Use option "Try without installing" would be better solution for a few days...